# How to set a 60 second limit to Audio recording

Tags: ios, swift, audio, ios9, xcode7

hi i am using IQAudioRecorder for audio recording. i want to set fix time for recording like user can record maximum upto 1 minut. so how can i do this?

Here is my code

```
func AudioFunction(){

    let controller = IQAudioRecorderController()

    controller.recordingTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    controller.playingTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    controller.delegate = self
    presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func audioRecorderController(controller: IQAudioRecorderController!, didFinishWithAudioAtPath filePath: String!){
    let d = NSDate()
    print(d)
      let vData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
      dataStr = vData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
      print(vData)
      print(filePath)

}
func audioRecorderControllerDidCancel(controller: IQAudioRecorderController!){

}


func playSound(soundName: String)
{

    let strpath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "/" +  soundName
    NSLog("File: %@", strpath)
    let coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:strpath)

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:coinSound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Govind Rakholiya :Am getting some issue whlie using controller.delegate=self.do u have a sample IQ recorder for swift

Answer (score 2):

Use an NSTimer. Instantiate an NSTimer when the recording starts.
At the end of 60 seconds, the timer will fire and call a method, that stops recording.

Here is the sample code :

```
    func startRecording(){

    let theTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60, target: self, selector: Selector("stopRecording"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    // Start recording here.

    theTimer.fire()
}

func stopRecording(){
    // Put the code to Stop recording here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now a property for the maximum allowed recording length. For your code:

controller.maximumRecordDuration = 60

Link to issue/resolution -- https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQAudioRecorderController/issues/17#issuecomment-205175475

Answer (score 0):

I think you left out the recording portion of your code, which may be in the IQAudioRecorderController.

But assuming that you have a recorder created similar to the below:

```
audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
audioRecorder.delegate = self
audioRecorder.record()
```

You can change the last line to the following to record for one minute:

```
audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 60.0)
```